# Certificate (cert) is not being attached to the header using Oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, certificate

We're using Oracle wallet to call a webservice however the certificate is not being attached to the header.

Our DBA has imported the certificate (generated through IE) into Oracle wallet.

Comment: I've never heard of attaching a certificate to a header of an HTTP request. Are you getting an error when trying to call the web service? If so, can you share the error as well as the code that is generating the error?

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed some code, no?